# Call routine when textbox is changed client-side using attributes.add

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, onchange

I am trying to find out if a vb routine can be called when a textbox is changed (in asp.net)

I've seen some examples where this code works, however it calls a javascript function, but I want it to call a vb routine (or function).

This is what I have so far:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    txtDO7_1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "checkifONCiscorrect();")
End Sub

Protected Sub checkifONCiscorrect()
    ' do some calculations here and show some messages
end sub
```

I want it to be client-side calculations, so no postback.
is this possible or with this code (attributes.add) on Page_Load you can only refer to javascript?

Answer (score 0):

These days, VB is a server-side language. If you want to execute a Visual Basic function (presumably VB.NET), you're going to have to either:

1. Postback

or

2. Use AJAX to invoke a Web service written in Visual Basic and return the results.

Mind you, VBScript used to be quite popular, but that required IE, and relying upon it is frowned upon (if not altogether impossible anymore).

Comment: VBScript is deprecated in IE11, and won't work in Edge mode: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384057(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As I suspected. Thanks for the clarification!